# Убрать перенос строки из подстановки в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярное выражение:

```
'~!!(.+?)!!~s'
```

Замена на:

```
<red>$1</red>
```

но дело в том что если текст имеет такую конструкцию

```
!!\n(перенос строки)привет это текст!!
```

то текст заменяется правильно, но после тэга `<red>(идетноваястрока) а потом уже соответсвенно текст`,

так вот вопрос заключается в том, как можно после того как мы изъяли из текста два восклицательных знака, "trim'нуть" его, а потом уже приложить тэг `<red>` из регулярного вырежния, чтобы внутри тэга `<red>(небылоэтогопереноса)привет я текст(издесьтоже)</red>`

спасибо

Comment: @Visman Вроде бы не дубликат, там автор говорит о том что выражение не срабатывает если есть "перенос строки" в любом месте текста, а здесь у автора все работает, просто нужно убрать символы разрыва строк в начале и конце текста который обработан регуляркой

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
$input = "!!\nfoo!!";
$output = preg_replace('~!!\s*(.+?)\s*!!~s', '<red>$1</red>', $input);
var_dump($output); // <red>foo</red>
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз это не дубликат, предлагаю решать проблему через функцию **preg_replace_callback()**

```
<?php
$input = "!!\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nfoo\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n!!";
$output = preg_replace_callback('~!!([^!]+(![^!]+)*)!!~', function($match){
     return '<red>' . trim($match[1]) . '</red>'; 
}, $input);
var_dump($output); // string(14) "<red>foo</red>"
```

Почему? Потому что такая [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/RY3Tjt/2)

```
~!!([^!]+(![^!]+)*)!!~
```

на больших текстах должна отрабатывать быстрее чем [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/RY3Tjt/1) с ленивым захватом символов `.*?`.

Comment: интересный вариант, но что делать если регулярка - массив? $patt = ['~\*\*([^*]+)\*\*~','~__(.+?)__~s', '~--(.+?)--~s',  '~!!\s*(.+?)\s*!!~s', '~""(.+?)""~', '~№№\s*(.+?)\s*№№~s'];
  $repl = ['<b>$1</b>', '<u>$1</u>', '<strike>$1</strike>', '<red>$1</red>', '<green>$1</green>', '<yellow>$1</yellow>'];
  $text = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $text);

Comment: @turik97, для множества замен пишут парсеры. А в данном случае можно использовать для каждой замены свою preg_replace_callback(), не столько много места функция занимает.