# Изменение регулярного выражения php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, есть регулярное выражение - `'#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#s',` не подскажите как можн оего изменить, чтобы текст внутри него как бы trim'ился? то есть из такого `[b]\n lol[/b]` можно было получить такое `[b]lol[/b]`

Comment: Возьмите уже наконец готовый парсер bb-кодов. На github их навалом.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699043/186083 только бб-код по другому выглядит. А автор тот же самый https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5681/186083 аккаунт сменил :)

Comment: @Visman, и они сделаны через регулярки?

Comment: @Qwertiy, кто они?

Comment: @Visman, готовые парсеры.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть полностью на регулярках, есть только частично.

Comment: @Visman я на сайте 2 недели не понимаю почему меня собственно уже к какому то дубликатеру приписали) если я что-то захочу задать я задам с этого аккаунта, зачем мне тратить время на регистрацию? да ссылку что вы прислали на bbcode, я что здесь один про них вопросы задаю? странная у вас какая-то деятельность, ответы на вопросы и помимо этого ведение каких-то расследований, такое в школе делают

Answer (score 0):

```
    preg_replace('~[_\W\d]~', '', $str)
```

Comment: Да ну? Как эта регулярка вообще с вопросом связана?

Answer (score 0):

Просто вынести пробельные символы `\s*` из захватываемой группы:

```
'#\[b\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/b\]#s'
```

Comment: Всего 31 тысяча шагов на 53 строках текста :) https://regex101.com/r/KeqYJN/1

Comment: @Visman, там 4340 символов. Меньше 8 шагов на символ. На мой взгляд очень даже нормально. Не?

Comment: Вот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699075/186083 с на много меньшим количеством шагов.

Comment: @Visman, во-первых, а время замерял?

Comment: А зачем? Нет ни какого смысла что-то замерять. Вопрошающему по фиг, лишь бы работало.

Comment: Я не уверен, что вызов функции для замены в обычных условиях (где выделены отдельные слова, а не все 4К символов) окажется выгоднее 7 сравнений.